# How import product multiselect attributes with profiler?

Tags: magento-1.8, import

How I can import multiselect attributes. I think I need create new advanced dataflow profile, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try multiselect attributes with below format

```
[data][space][comma][space][data][space]...
```

Example:

```
Green , Orange , Blue , Red , Grey
```

Comment: magento 1938: this does not or  no longer seem to work: do we need to set a separator somwhere? or has this been changed?

Comment: Not working as expected in 2.3.1